# PhpStorm caret behavior is weird (not block-character setting)

Tags: phpstorm, settings, caret

My PhpStorm is acting strange, I think it has to do with a key combination I accidently made when using multiple cursors, but I can't find how to revert it back to the normal behavior.

Anyone knows how I can disable the behavior as shown in the GIF?
[image: PhpStorm caret behavior]

Why would someone need a feature like this anyway...

Comment: Did you try restarting PhpStorm?

Comment: Maybe clearing PHPStorm cache and restart would do.

Comment: I had tried that, obviously. But it didn't had any effect the first time. It took two restarts for this behavior to disapear. Also I've been discharged from the mental institute ;)